# In Dynamics AX : what type of FactBox added to a listPage, will appear only in the client environnement

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I need to ensure that a Fact Box I add to a AX 2012 list page will appear only in the client environment. Which type of Fact Box should you use?
 - A. Cue Group
 - B. Cue 
 - C. Form Part 
 - D. Info Part

I m preparing for the Ax 2012 R3 certification exam. I didnt anderstant this question.
Correct Answer: C
My Response: D (Incorrect)
how could it be a form part, any explanation please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly spelled out in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg844683.aspx) although the other way around.

> Form Part:
>   A part that represents a pointer to a form. You use a form part when you want a form to appear in the FactBox pane, enhanced preview, or preview pane.
>   **Caution: Enterprise Portal does not support the use of a form as a FactBox.** To use a form part with Enterprise Portal, you use the ManagedContentItem property to specify a User Control. The specified User Control appears in Enterprise Portal as the FactBox.